# Creating a View that can handle a Form post and an Edit post

Tags: python, django

I am currently working with Django 5.0 and want to create a page that can handle both Form post and Edit post. I was able to get the view to handle this by using a try/except approach but I am running into the problem into formatting my url. I know that you need to be able to call the entry id in order to update a form post, but how do you pass that id in the form action?

url

`path('test/', views.test, name='test'),`

views

```
def test(request, log_id = None):

    log = Test.objects.all()

    if log_id == None:
        if request.method != 'POST':
            form = TestForm()
        else:
            form = TestForm(data=request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('home:home')
    else:
       
        if request.method != 'POST':
            form = TestForm(instance=log)
        else:
            form = TestForm(instance=log, data=request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('test', args=[form.id]))

    context = {
        'form':form,
        'log':log,
    }
    return render(request, 'forms/test.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming from this `return render(request, 'forms/test.html', context)` that your app_name is forms and your template name is test. I'm not sure why you set log_id = None, but I refactored your code. Perhaps more context as to why you presented your code that way might be needed. In the mean time, if you try the refactored version below, you will be able to handle form post just fine.

```
def test(request, log_id):
 
    log = Test.objects.get(id=log_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = TestForm()
    else:
        form = TestForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_test = form.save(commit=False)
            new_test.log = title
            new_test.save()
            return redirect('forms:log',log_id=log_id) 

    context = {'log': log, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'forms/test.html', context)
```

Then app urls.py should be `path('test/<int:log_id>/', views.test, name='test'),`